# Login with twitter failed "Error obtaining user auth token"

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I want to use login twitter in my app, I followed all instructions in twitter dashboard and installation guide but when I run my app it gives me this error

in dashboard there's callback url I don't know what to set in it
I used this :
Callback URL
http://twitterkit-7K3f5fZ98fNFGu7N8Aslo936c

here is the codes I used in my AppDelegate

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:"7K3f5fZ98fNFGu7N8Aslo936c", consumerSecret:"FYfOSgeGd5VAge6DuxersYIfpSaLGPfUK5cME50Z1KpbTLI2WK")
  return true
 }
```

```
application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
 if TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options){
            return true
        }
  return false
        }
```

//and in LoginViewController

```
 // Swift
        let logInButton = TWTRLogInButton(logInCompletion: { session, error in
            if (session != nil) {
                print("signed in as \(session?.userName)");
            } else {
                print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription)");
            }
        })
        logInButton.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(logInButton)
```

there is the errors I got when I run the app

```
2019-08-03 17:44:35.503573+0200 Kuwait Calendar[2401:238906] [TwitterKit] Error obtaining user auth token.
error: Optional("Request failed: forbidden (403)")
```

or this error

```
2019-08-03 17:19:11.530475+0200 Kuwait Calendar[2198:174628] CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    ptcl = htps;
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sdmn = "https://api.twitter.com";
    srvr = "api.twitter.com";
    sync = syna;
}
2019-08-03 17:19:11.820783+0200 Kuwait Calendar[2198:174430] [TwitterKit] Error obtaining user auth token.
error: Optional("Request failed: unauthorized (401)")
```

Comment: are aware of twikket is not longer working

Comment: @kjoe but I have an app still can retrieve data from twitter.

Comment: try replacing your callback url with 'twitterkit-CONSUMERKEY: //' without the single quotes of course.

Comment: just a suggested never ever show your api keys and api SECRET it can harm you in  future. :)